# C++ ExceptionHandeler: terminate ist always called

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I just startet using Exceptions in C++, but every time an Exception is called my Programm terminates with:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException1'
>
> `what()`:  Hier koennte Ihre Werbung stehen

and I don't know why.
Note that i have to use C++03, because I'm programming for a QNX System.

My Exception Class:

```
using namespace std;
#include <exception>

class Exception : public exception
{
public:
    Exception(const char* msg): msg_((char*)msg) {};

    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return msg_;
    }

    virtual ~Exception() throw(){};

private:
    char* msg_;
};

class MyException1 : public Exception
{
public:
    MyException1(const char* message):Exception(message){}
};
```

The Class that throws and catches the Exception:

```
using namespace std;
#include "ExceptionUseExample.h"
#include <iostream>

void ExceptionUseExample::doSomethingElse() throw()
{
    throw MyException1("Hier koennte Ihre Werbung stehen");
}


void ExceptionUseExample::doSomething()
{
    try
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
    catch (MyException1& e)
    {
        cerr << "catched MyException1: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (if I'm not wrong) is in `doSomethingElse()`; you declare it as `throw()`, so you declare that it doesn't throw exceptions. Throwing an exception, it kill the program.

You should remove `throw()` or add the type of the throwed exception; someting like

```
void doSomethingElse() throw(MyException1)
```

or

```
void doSomethingElse() throw(Exception)
```

En passant, I report you another dangerous point (even, if I'm not wrong).

The constructor of your `Exception` receive a pointer to `char` and copy it to a member of the class. But who ensure that it points to a valid (allocated) memory area when (`what()`) you use it? 
I suppose you should make a copy of the pointed area.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try it soon.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to use std::string internally and return str.c_str() for what().